# How to avoid Django to change field on model migration when using makemigrations?

Tags: python, sql, django

I need to avoid `python manage.py makemigrations` to alter the uniqueness of a field. The reason behind it is that if I leave the `unique=True` on the model the function `bulk_create` with `update_conflicts` generates the following error:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification`

This error does not occurs if I migrate with `unique=True` then I remove it when running the app. It may be a bug on the `update_conflicts` implementation as it's recent.

Here is the function to `bulk_create`:

```
class MyModelListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        my_models = [MyModel(**item) for item in validated_data]    
        MyModel.objects.bulk_create(
            my_models,
            update_conflicts=True,
            unique_fields=["my_field"],
            update_fields=["other_field", "another_field"],
        )
```

Here is the initial model creation:

```
# 0001_initial.py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True

    dependencies = []

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="MyModel",
            fields=[
                (
                    "id",
                    models.BigAutoField(
                        auto_created=True,
                        primary_key=True,
                        serialize=False,
                        verbose_name="ID",
                    ),
                ),
                ("my_field", models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=50, unique=True)),
                ...
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Here is what I want to avoid when rerunning `makemigrations` as I want to keep field uniqueness.

```
# 0002_alter_my_table_my_field.py
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ("my_database", "0001_initial"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name="my_model",
            name="my_field",
            field=models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=50),  # I need this to continue unique
        ),
    ]
``
```

Comment: That sounds more like it's an error coming from the database itself rather than Django. Maybe the constraints on that table are broken. Assuming this is Postgres, can you get into the dbshell `python manage.py dbshell` and post the output of `\d <your_table_name_here>`?

Answer (score 0):

In the end the issue that it automatically tries to validate my unique fields. I had to add the following configuration so it wouldn't validate `my_field` that is a unique field

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        list_serializer_class = MyModelListSerializer
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {"my_field": {"validators": []}}
```